# JPA: Query that returns multiple entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm writing a JPQL query that joins across three tables. In my resultlist I would like to get all three entities per matching row (hope that makes sense).

Any ideas?

Hibernate 3.x is my JPA provider.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

IIRC, you can do a `SELECT o1, o2, o3 FROM EntityA o1, EntityB o2, EntityC o3 WHERE ....`, and the result will be a `List<Object[3]>`, where the array contents will contain the o1,o2,o3 values.

Comment: @John: Additionally, you can invoke constructors from hql, so you could also do `select new Foo(o1, o2, o3)...` and get a List<Foo> instead of a List<Object[]>.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to use a JPA TypedQuery:  myEntityManager.createQuery("select o1, o2 ...", <what to put here?>)

Comment: What if you wanted to use setFirstResult that would actually apply to the concatenation of both lists? ie I want to be able to return a paginated list which is the concatenation of the result for the two entities being queried.

Comment: @Thomas What, like [SQL UNION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080555/jpql-equivalent-of-sql-query-using-unions-and-selecting-constants)?

Comment: @Tassos, yes but the entities will have different number of fields etc... the more I think about it the more it seems very difficult to have out of the box. I guess I am dreaming of JPA wizardry here...

Comment: @Thomas, the entities have each their own complement of fields, you're mixing your internal SQL and JPA models :-). `SELECT o1, o2, o3 FROM EntityA o1, EntityB o2 WHERE ...` will return to you rows with exactly 2 columns; if your JPA provider supports `SELECT o1 FROM EntityA o1 UNION ALL SELECT o2 from EntityB o2` then you will get a List with only one item, which is either EntityA or Entity B.

Comment: And you cannot do a left outer joins between unrelated entities until you upgrade to Hibernate 5.1
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16

Comment: How to do this query in a criteria ?

Comment: but how can we display an array of objects in JSF

Answer (score 41):

This is a Spring Data sample, however its works the same way in JPA

```
//HQL query
 @Query("SELECT c,l,p,u FROM  Course c, Lesson l, Progress p, User u "
            + "WHERE c.id=l.courseId AND l.id = p.lessonId AND p.userId = u.id AND u.id=:userId AND c.id=:courseId")
    public List<Object[]> getLessonsWithProgress(@Param("userId") Integer userId, @Param("courseId")Integer courseId);
```

Then, I call this method and print the results:

```
List<Object[]> lst = courseRepository.getLessonsWithProgress(userId, courseId);
for (Object o[] : lst) {
    Course c = (Course) o[0];
    Lesson l = (Lesson) o[1];
    Progress p = (Progress) o[2];
    User u = (User) o[3];
    //all the classes: Course, Lesson, Progress and User have the toString() overridden with the database ID;    
    System.out.printf("\nUser: %s \n Lesson: %s \n Progress: %s \n Course: %s",u,l,p,c);
}
```

The output @Test is here:

```
User: com.cassio.dao.model.User[ id=1965 ] 
Lesson: com.cassio.dao.model.Lesson[ id=109 ] 
Progress: com.cassio.dao.model.Progress[ id=10652 ] 
Course: com.cassio.dao.model.Course[ id=30 ]
```

Cheers

Comment: hi Cassion, but what in case i just want only Coursname,LessionID,ProgressID and username..then what to do? how to handle list data. Because at that time this row can not be case by any class

Comment: Hi Utkal, considering my sample code, Course, Lesson, Progress and User are objects. You can get the desired String or Integer making @Override in toString() method of each class. In the meantime, the best practice to that case is change the HQL query, instead get Course c, you can do it that way SELECT c.name, l.id, progress.id, and u.firstname FROM ... Thus you will get the Strings and Integers instead the complex objects.

Comment: How can I get List<Object[]> type of result from a criteria query ?

Comment: @user1735921 I dont think CriteriaQuery will be able to return an array of Object[], may you  can achieve it trying to adapt it to a generic type <T>, or may using a DTO Object.

Comment: @CassioSeffrin I realised its not possible, so had to make a custom projection class (or it can also return a List<Map<String,Object> type if we don't wanna use a class where string is the alias to column and object is the value which can be type casted to the actual model field type).

Comment: @user1735921, you made the right choice. If you're working with spring data the projections are the best option, projections are what I mean DTO (data transfer object). Take a look at session 4:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts

Answer (score 2):

Since You are asking `JPA: Query that returns multiple entities`, EclipseLink too comes under it. And I reached on this question googling for EclipseLink. So here is my solution. Hope it works for you.

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Post p where   p.publisher.pubId= :ID order by p.createdAt desc",
                Object[].class);
query.setParameter("ID", publisherID);
```

Then you can loop through the result objects and cast them accordingly.

```
for (Object result : query.getResultList()) {
            myList.add((Post) result);
        }
```

You can also try this,

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Post p where   p.publisher.pubId= :ID order by p.createdAt desc");
```

Reference:http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL

Comment: what if i need to get the data from 2 entities say publisher and books?

Answer (score 2):

In case of many to one or one to many relationship how to get multiple records of one of the entities? lets say A is one entity and B is another entity but they have one to many relationship and when you get result you expect B has one record and A has more than 1 record? My query is as below but I don't know how shall I get multiple records of 2nd entity?

```
@Query("SELECT wl, gr FROM WatchList as wl, GeozoneReference gr " +
            "WHERE wl.watchlistId = gr.objWatchList.watchlistId " +
            "AND wl.watchlistId =:watchlistId")
    List<Object[]> findWatchlistByWatchlistId(@Param("watchlistId") Long watchlistId);
```