# JPQL equivalent of SQL query using unions and selecting constants

Tags: jpa, jpql

I've written a SQL query that basically selects from a number of tables to determine which ones have rows that were created since a particular date.  My SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT widget_type FROM(
  SELECT 'A' as widget_type
  FROM widget_a
  WHERE creation_timestamp > :cutoff
  UNION
  SELECT 'B' as widget_type
  FROM widget_b
  WHERE creation_timestamp > :cutoff
) types
GROUP BY widget_type
HAVING count(*)>0
```

That works well in SQL but I recently found that, while JPA may use unions to perform "table per class" polymorphic queries, [JPQL does not support unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062501/jpa-only-executes-first-select-statement-in-union) in queries.  So that leaves me wondering whether JPA has an alternative I could use to accomplish the same thing.

In reality, I would be querying against a dozen tables, not just two, so I would like to avoid doing separate queries.  I would also like to avoid doing a native SQL query for portability reasons.

In the question I linked to above, it was asked whether the entities that map to widget_a and widget_b are part of the same inheritance tree.  Yes, they are.  However, if I selected from their base class, I don't believe I would have a way of specifying different string constants for the different child entities, would I?  If I could select an entity's class name instead of a string I provide, that might serve my purpose too.  But I don't know if that's possible either.  Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you want to re-implement something that's already available out-of-the-box in JPA: inheritance?

Comment: Actually, I do use inheritance when I want to query for the objects themselves.  And it works great.  But like the question says, what I want to do here is query for which entity TYPES have been used (created) recently, not query for the entities themselves.  If you have a way of doing so, I would love to know

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did a little more searching and found a (seemingly obscure) feature of JPA that serves my purpose perfectly.  What I found is that JPA 2 has a `type` keyword that allows you to limit polymorphic queries to a particular subclass, like so:

```
SELECT widget
FROM BaseWidget widget
WHERE TYPE(widget) in (WidgetB, WidgetC)
```

I've found that JPA (or at least Hibernate as a JPA implementation) allows you to use `type` not only in constraints but also in select lists.  This is approximately what my query ended up looking like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TYPE(widget)
FROM BaseWidget widget
WHERE widget.creationTimestamp > :cutoff
```

That query returns a list of `Class` objects.  My original query was selecting string literals because that's closest to what I might have done in SQL.  Selecting `Class` is actually preferable in my case.  But if I did prefer to select a constant based on an entity's type, that is the exact scenario that [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#gjjnd) uses to illustrate `case` statements:

```
SELECT p.name
CASE TYPE(p)
  WHEN Student THEN 'kid'
  WHEN Guardian THEN 'adult'
  WHEN Staff THEN 'adult'
  ELSE 'unknown'
END
FROM Person p
```

Answer (score 0):

Some JPA providers do support UNION,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#UNION

but your query seems very complex, and non object-oriented, so using a native SQL query would probably be best.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been developing using Hibernate and plan on eventually migrating my application to Google App Engine, neither of which support JPQL unions.  Luckily, I discovered JPA 2's `type` keyword, which is perfect for queries like the one in my question.  Take a look at my answer if you are curious about the details.