# Querying more than two entities

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

JPQl Am new in jpa and I want to query all fields from two entities and then use the entity classes getters to access the data .

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u(*),f(*) FROM User u join Employee f in u.empid=f.id WHERE u.username = :login AND u.passowrd = :pass");
        q.setParameter("login", usernameTextField.getText().trim());
        q.setParameter("pass", passwordPasswordField.getText().trim());
```

Error

> Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
>   Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u(*),f(*) FROM User u join Employee  f in u.empid=f.id WHERE u.username = :login AND u.passowrd = :pass].
>   [9, 9] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
>   [10, 10] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
>   [15, 15] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
>   [16, 16] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
>   [7, 8] The SELECT clause has 'u' and '(*)' that are not separated by a comma.
>
>   [13, 14] The SELECT clause has 'f' and '(*)' that are not separated by a comma.
>   [56, 57] The FROM clause has 'User u JOIN Employee f IN u.empid=' and 'f.id ' that are not separated by a comma.
>   [46, 57]  The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.
>   [62, 62] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.

Thank you all for your contributions......so far I have amended the query up to this

```
SELECT u,f 
FROM User u, Employee f  
WHERE u.username = :login AND u.passowrd = :pass AND u.empid=f.id
```

and now I am getting this error

> internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id))' at line 1
>   Error Code: 1064
>   Call: SELECT t0.id, t0.level, t0.passowrd, t0.username, t0.empid, t1.id, t1.address, t1.email, t1.gender, t1.idnum, t1.name, t1.phone, t1.staffcol, t1.dept FROM user t0, staff t1 WHERE (((t0.username = ?) AND (t0.passowrd = ?)) AND (t0.empid = t1.id.t1.id))
>   bind => [2 parameters bound]
>   Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=User sql="SELECT t0.id, t0.level, t0.passowrd, t0.username, t0.empid, t1.id, t1.address, t1.email, t1.gender, t1.idnum, t1.name, t1.phone, t1.staffcol, t1.dept FROM user t0, staff t1 WHERE (((t0.username = ?) AND (t0.passowrd = ?)) AND (t0.empid = t1.id.t1.id))")

Comment: So what is your question? What is the problem in the code you posted?

Comment: Show your entities.  It's odd that user has an empid instead of an employee reference.  Is an employee meant to be a type of user?

Answer (score 1):

Question already asked:
[JPA: Query that returns multiple entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877857/jpa-query-that-returns-multiple-entities)
(In this example it's hibernate what is an implementation von jpa)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u, f FROM User u, Employee f WHERE u.empid = f.id and u.username = :login AND u.passowrd = :pass");
        q.setParameter("login", usernameTextField.getText().trim());
        q.setParameter("pass", passwordPasswordField.getText().trim());
Object[] result = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();
User user = result[0];
Employee emp = result[1];
```

**edit:** This part of your translated query looks like you have a mapping problem in your Employee class:

```
... t1.id.t1.id ...
```

Comment: This is correct answer. Probably you (morrizDroid) may not refer proper class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do such a thing and here is why.

The query you post is "inspired" by the relational approach, i.e. you query for a table with arbitrary fields (maybe produced by the join and maybe even artificial).

JPA is by nature is an ORM framework - which means it encapsulates a relation structure by wrapping it in Object.
So, you have to work with Objects as its common in relational data world.

This means that you always should query for an object.
Now how about the join you've mentioned?

Actually join is a way to get a projection in relational data modeling world, again its not for object oriented world, here we operate with inheritance and composition.
You may model the same relation with these mentioned above.

So in object based data modeling world you should think about the "relation" between user and employee as like these are objects and not different tables - think as a object oriented language programmer and not an sql user.

In this particular case my first bet would be saying that a user 'is an' employee with some additional information (I might be wrong its more a question of data modeling, it might be an opposite, so you should think about this).

So you define class Employee in java
then you define class User in java:

```
class Employee {

}

class User extends Employee {


}
```

And then you provide a relational mapping to this hierarchy of objects.
There are 3 different strategies for mapping such a thing, you might be interesting on reading  [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns-mapping)

Hope this helps

Comment: All i want is just to query the user details all of it and corresponding datail in the employee entity instead of querying each field in the query string like(Select u.username,u.password,e.name,e.departmentid from user.....)

Comment: Sorry but you've completely misunderstood me. Its possible to do "SELECT from User" (without mentioning fields) but the point is that you get an object, not a projection. The whole point of ORM framework is to encapsulate the work with relations because its not object oriented. Please read carefully my post.

Answer (score 0):

**I am not expert but I assume:**

Make your return type main entity like following.

```
public User methodWhichReturnsListAfterQuery(){    
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u join u.employee f WHERE  u.empid=f.id AND u.username = :login AND u.passowrd = :pass");
    q.setParameter("login", usernameTextField.getText().trim());
    q.setParameter("pass", passwordPasswordField.getText().trim());
     return (User)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

**I assume your main entity is `User`**

Your `User` entity like following:

```
public class User Implements Serializable{
    .
    .
    //Some relation type
    private Employee employee;
    .
    .
    //getter() and setter()
}
```

get values after query

```
User user= methodWhichReturnsListAfterQuery ();
```

Now you can get values like this:

```
String userName=user.getUserName();
String password=user.getPassword();
String name=user.getEmployee().getName();
Long departMentId=user.getEmoloyee().getDepartmentId();
```

Hope you get...