# Spring Data pagination

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination, spring-data-jpa

Just face strange behavior of Spring Data JPA 2.2.0.

Product and Category are two very simple entities with one-to-many relations. Notice that in my case some products could have no category.

I make this query

```
@Query("select p, c" +
        "from Product p " +
        "left join fetch Category c on p.category.id = c.id " +
        "where (:categoryId = -1L or c.id = :categoryId) and " +
        "(:priceFrom is null or p.price >= :priceFrom) and " +
        "(:priceTo is null or p.price <= :priceTo)")
Page<Product> filterProducts(@Param("categoryId") Long categoryId,
                             @Param("priceFrom") BigDecimal priceFrom,
                             @Param("priceTo") BigDecimal priceTo,
                             Pageable pageable);
```

But method call returns `Page<Object[]>` instead of `Page<Product>`. If I change `Page` to `List` in return type all going to be fine. Why it works this way? Is it possible to change this behavior?

I use `select p, c` to fill resulting products with all data from product and category by one query. Without `c` Hibernate doing some additional queries to get Categories.

Comment: can you check if this also happens if you use an existing Spring Data repo method, e.g. `Page<Product> findAll();`?

Comment: maybe also post your related entity classes... could help

Comment: possibly a duplicate... plz have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877857/jpa-query-that-returns-multiple-entities

Comment: As far as I know to use Lazy load of a field it has to have `optional=false` parameter. But `Category` is optional. You can try to add `EmptyCategory` value instead of null. And then try to use `join fetch` instead of `left join fetch`

Answer (score 0):

does your repository interface extend `JpaRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository`, e.g. like this (where `Long` is the type of your entities `@Id` field:

```
@Repository
interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    // your custom repo methods...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Query("from Product p left join fetch p.category c " +
       "where (:categoryId = -1L or c.id = :categoryId) and " +
       "(:priceFrom is null or p.price >= :priceFrom) and " +
       "(:priceTo is null or p.price <= :priceTo)")
Page<Product> filterProducts(@Param("categoryId") Long categoryId,
                                     @Param("priceFrom") BigDecimal priceFrom,
                                     @Param("priceTo") BigDecimal priceTo,
                                     Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: This query fetches every Category by separate select. I'm looking for a way how to force Hibernate to do that by one query with a join.

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the proper page info, Spring JPA also need the maxinum number of rows. (for calculating the page numbers). In order to get this you need to provide a `countQuery` in addition to the original query definition:

```
@Query(value = "select p, c" +
        "from Product p " +
        "left join fetch Category c on p.category.id = c.id " +
        "where (:categoryId = -1L or c.id = :categoryId) and " +
        "(:priceFrom is null or p.price >= :priceFrom) and " +
        "(:priceTo is null or p.price <= :priceTo)",
       countQuery = "select count(p.id)" +
        "from Product p " +
        "left join fetch Category c on p.category.id = c.id " +
        "where (:categoryId = -1L or c.id = :categoryId) and " +
        "(:priceFrom is null or p.price >= :priceFrom) and " +
        "(:priceTo is null or p.price <= :priceTo)",
```

)
    Page filterProducts(@Param("categoryId") Long categoryId,
                                 @Param("priceFrom") BigDecimal priceFrom,
                                 @Param("priceTo") BigDecimal priceTo,
                                 Pageable pageable);